# Xcode error when Package.swift platform changed from v13 to v14 "v14 unavailable"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, package

I need features in iOS v14. I have a local package. When I change the platforms item in "Packages.swift",

platforms: [.macOS(.v10_15), .iOS(.v14)],

I get the error 'v14' unavailable.

The app deployment target is set to 14.1.
I'm running Xcode v12.5.1

Comment: Looks like v14 was introduced in Package Description 5.3. I'm at 5.2

Answer (score 7):

There is a commented line at the top of "Package.swift"

// swift-tools-version:5.2

When I changes the 5.2 -> 5.3 the error cleared. Why would a "comment" line have any effect?

Comment: this worked for me, I'd say you can mark the answer as correct. I assume that Xcode/the compiler is parsing the comment before parsing the file and that's why it's in a comment ¯\_(ツ)_/¯